# Underlining text posted to slack

Tags: webhooks, slack

I am trying to see if there is a way to underline a text posted to slack. I am using webhook for posting messages to slack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. See https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting for the available message formatting options.

Comment: Thanks smarx. Yes , I looked at it and didn't find an option & hence posted this question. Thanks for letting me know that there are no other options available.

Answer (score 12):

You can approximate it with Unicode’s COMBINING LOW LINE character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0332/index.htm . Before posting, split your string along grapheme boundaries and insert a COMBINING LOW LINE after each. This sort of works, but with Slack’s default font the underline sometimes splits visually between characters. It’s enough though to give an impression, which might be what you want if, for example, you’re trying to give an example of the position of a link within a piece of text.

Comment: With [COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON BELOW](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/035f/index.htm) you can approximate it even better, by putting the diacritic character before each character except the last one (to comply with slack's font) if is *almost* a perfect underline